# Different session data for multiple passport js strategy

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, passport.js

I have implemented a JWT based passport strategy to protect my express API to authenticated users only. Also, now I need to give an option to the users to connect with Linkedin and add more details to their profile. I am using [passport-linkedin-oauth2](https://github.com/auth0/passport-linkedin-oauth2) to connect with LinkedIn.

I am getting all the required info from the users' linkedin profile as mentioned in the above link. But the issue I am facing is that the, `/auth/linkedin` and the `/auth/linkedin/callback` routes are to be protected to be available to only authenticated users. I have implemented the same as given below, but the issue is that the session i.e. user data from the JWT strategy is being lost due to the linkedin strategy, even though I have instantiated two passport objects.

`user.js` route file:

```
const pass = require('passport').Passport;
const router = express.Router();

const passport = new pass();
const linkedinPassport = new pass();

router.use(passport.initialize({userProperty: "access"}));
router.use(passport.session());
require('../config/passport')(passport);

router.use(linkedinPassport.initialize({userProperty: "linkedin"}));
router.use(linkedinPassport.session());
require('../config/linkedin')(linkedinPassport);

passport.serializeUser((user, done) => { console.log("Serializing ID: " + user._id);  done(null, user); });

linkedinPassport.serializeUser((user, done) => { console.log("L: " + user);  done(null, user)});

router.get('/auth/linkedin', passport.authenticate('jwt', {session: true}), linkedinPassport.authenticate('linkedin', {session: true}));

router.get('/auth/linkedin/callback', passport.authenticate('jwt', {session: true}), linkedinPassport.authenticate('linkedin', {session: true}), (req, res) => {

console.log(req.access);
console.log(req.linkedin);


});

module.exports = router;
```